# Программирование офисных приложений

Tags: open-office

Подскажите литературу доступную (желательно в электронном виде). Только не MSOfice, а OpenOffice.org BASIC.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте забил на OpenOffice и занялся LibreOffice.
То же самое в принципе, но ИМХО либра будет более востребована.

Comment: А разница-то какая? Libre - это тот же OpenOffice с каким-то сторонними изменениями. Те же яйца, только в профиль.

Answer (score 4):

Ну, в первую очередь следует прочесть официальные источники, такие как [Developer Guide](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OpenOffice.org_Developers_Guide), [OpenOffice API Reference](http://api.openoffice.org/) и [OpenOffice.org BASIC Programming Guide](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide).

Затем, можно и прошвырнуться по следующим строчкам из гугла:

- [OpenOffice BASIC Programmes guide in CHM](http://a32.me/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/oobg.zip)
- [OpenOffice.org Macro Information](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php)
- [Programming OpenOffice.org with Visual Basic](http://www.kalitech.fr/clients/doc/VB_APIOOo_en.html)

Comment: Я пишу диплом по этой теме, так что одними официальными источниками не обойтись, мне нужна вся возможная литература.

Comment: На самом деле, официальная литература - обычно самая важная. Именно она является первоисточником всех сведений (после авторов, конечно же).

Comment: Мне нужна теория программирования офисных приложений, официальные источники OpenOffice.org дают только общее представление.

Comment: Поддерживаю. Поскольку производитель лучше знает свой продукт и более заинтересован в его успехе по сравнению с другими, то его документация (официальный ресурс) обязана быть лучшей.

Comment: Теория? Но теория программирования офисных приложений (если она вообще есть) не может быть привязана ни к языку, ни к конкретной платформе.. К тому же, как де это общее представление? Они дают как раз наоборот практические сведения для того чтобы начать и reference для выполнения самой разработки. Это не общие, а как раз слишком конкретные сведения.

Answer (score 0):

Сам использовал для ознакомлния и как вводный курс Эндрю Питоньяк. "OpenOffice.org Объяснение Макросов"